# How to auto refresh cells of datagrid using gwtp?

Tags: gwtp

I am doing a project using gwtp.When I add any new entries in the datagrid,the cells are not updated instantly.I need to refresh the browser to reveal the change.Can you please provide me the best solution for auto refreshing of the datagrid when certain changes are made to the cells?

Answer (score 0):

add the record to dataprovider and

try using `datagrid.redraw();`